# Do natural lycanthropes still receive racial bonuses from their base race?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, lycanthropy

Playing a natural born weretiger, as opposed to one who was afflicted with it. I'm several levels in, and now I wonder if I've made a mistake. Should my racial bonuses as a human still apply, since that's what I am when I'm not in my animal or hybrid form?

Answer (score 4):

Being a [lycanthrope](http://dndsrd.net/monstersKtoL.html#lycanthrope) changes neither a creature's race nor its type (despite the lycanthrope gaining the subtype [shapechanger](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#shapechanger)), so a lycanthrope keeps the features and traits of its race. Even a natural lycanthrope has a race like human or elf rather than, for instance, the creature's race being lycanthrope or weretiger. This means, for example, a [human](http://dndsrd.net/races.html#human) [weretiger](http://dndsrd.net/monstersKtoL.html#weretiger) keeps its bonus feat and extra skill points.

However, ask the DM if the extra skill points due to being human apply to the human weretiger's animal Hit Dice. [*Cooper's Compendium of Corrected Creatures*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy888m?Coopers-Compendium-of-Corrected-Creatures-Bundle) says *No*, but your DM's opinion may differ.